# How to pass a struct into a function call

Tags: c++, function, struct

I am trying to Pass a struct called "coordinate"  into a function that has 2 int's, so when the function is called, integers can be entered as the parameter for the function. Example:

Here is my struct I am wanting to use:

```
struct coordinate
{
    int row;
    int col;
};
```

and the function prototype looks like this:

```
bool    IsInMaze(coordinate);
```

What I am wanting to do is call the function like this...

```
IsInMaze(1,5);
```

so that 1 will be the row and 5 will be the column. The function is basically checking if the coordinate's (int's) are within the size of particular dimensions... like this

```
bool MazeClass::IsInMaze(coordinate location)
{
    if(location.row < 0 || location.row > height || location.col < 0 || location.col > width)
        return false;
    else 
        return true;
}
```

but I get this error...

```
ola4A1.cc: In function \u2018int main(int, char**)\u2019:
ola4A1.cc:30: error: no matching function for call to \u2018MazeClass::IsInMaze(int, int)\u2019
MazeClass.h:30: note: candidates are: bool MazeClass::IsInMaze(coordinate)
ola4A1.cc:35: error: no matching function for call to \u2018MazeClass::IsInMaze(int, int)\u2019
MazeClass.h:30: note: candidates are: bool MazeClass::IsInMaze(coordinate)
```

I have never really been taught this, so I assume I am just not understanding this right. How would I be able to write this function that I can call it the way I am wanting to call it? Thanks.

Comment: Call like this ``coordinate c {1, 2}; IsVisited(c);`` or declare an overloaded version: ``bool IsVisited(int, int)``.

Comment: Your function is called `IsVisited` or `IsInMaze`?

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong function prototype over RedBaron, it is "IsInMaze"

Comment: Try `IsInMaze({1,5});`, assuming you have a C++0x-compliant compiler.

Comment: And most of the time, you want to declare ``IsInMaze(coordinate &)`` instead of ``IsInMaze(coordinate)``.

Comment: @gongzhitaao: or `IsInMaze(const coordinate &)` since `IsInMaze` probably should not modify the coordinate

Comment: In some versions of C++ you can call it like this:
IsVisited({1,5});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where you're going wrong is expecting that the contents of your struct may be passed as arguments to a function that expects an instance of your struct.

`IsInMaze(int, int)` is not the same as `IsInMaze(coordinate)`.  To properly call your function as declared, you must create a `coordinate` first, and pass that:

```
coorindate c;
c.row = 1;
c.col = 5;
IsInMaze(c);
```

Alternatively, you can declare another `IsInMaze` which takes two `int` parameters:

```
bool IsInMaze(int row, int col);
```

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the answer. I believe I understand it now.